# How do I get the word count from the TinyMCE editor?

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

I have a web page with several textareas, each uses the TinyMCE editor.

The wordcount plugin shows me the word count in the bottom right corner of the editor. However, I also need to retrieve the value from the editor, not just display it.

How do I ask the editor to give me the word count as a Javascript variable so that I can display it outside of the editor?

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the element with the count is called: `content-word-count`.

You can get the value of that element with something like this in js:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('content-word-count').innerHTML)
```

or with jQuery you can do something like this:

```
parseInt($('#content-word-count').text())
```